# How to solve memory leaks , Is useing service a option?

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

My app is very slow, than ı searched web and find out there are memeory leaks on my app. But the problem is ı have tons of codes and too many activities. There are tons of refenrences and leaks. Its gonna be really hard work if ı do this way. Than I tougth if I transfer all codes to a services (as ı understand the services is not leaking memory) this would be easier for me. I wnant to ask that, if you had this statuation, than how would you try to solve it? I learned about memory managment 4 days ago and 10 hours of day learned about it. But ı dont want to go wrong direction again. And my app live on market and users still waiting for a update. I need to be fast and affactive more than I can be. How would you salve this leaks on fastest way ? Is servis realy a option ?Thanks..

Comment: The short answer is no. It is not your solution to use a service. Some work is suitable to be in a service, some work is suitiable to be in an Activity. So, read the SDK documentation to know what to use for each work

Comment: No you can't directly say that you can just move the code to the service and that will solve your problem.Don't go for complete app re-factor at once, pick a particular module or patch fix it and move forward to have long run stable release

Comment: Service is not the solution. If I were you I would have debugged the whole code and find the memory leak problems and fix them :)

Comment: At first thanks for quick responses , looks like debuging leaks is better way..I know ı cant do everything in services and olsa ı gonna need to many boradcasts and services to do this. So solving problems looks like better way.

Comment: You could start with using a word processor that recognizes gramar and spell errors and run your questions through it before asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to clear all leaks and make a better codding. This is absolute way. By the way, for more performance, when a activity is hidden clear all data that took. and clear all images. if activity is active again reload all contents again.
also: create a clas and make a static instance of aplication context. then call this where you wrigth .getaplicationcontext(). this thecnic called by weak reference. by this your activities will be garbace collected.
and use this.isfinishing() method at onpost() method of every asyctask.
you can use onstart and onstop calls for this. my apps ram usage was 250 mb and now 70mb.